# Eclipselink UNION + SELECT NEW

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, union

I am using eclipselink 2.4.2. I have to do a query that uses a UNION and the SELECT NEW clause.

My jpa query is like this:

```
SELECT new com.*.*.MyObject(s.field1, s.field2, s.field3) 
FROM MyEntityBean1 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT 
new com.*.*.MyObject(s.field1, s.field2, s.field3) 
FROM MyEntityBean2 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT ...
```

but eclipselink transforms it in this sql query:

```
SELECT t0.COLUMN1, t0.COLUMN2, ... FROM 
TABLE1 t1 WHERE (t1.COLUMN3 = ?) 
UNION (SELECT  FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE (t2.COLUMN3 = ?)) UNION (...)
```

As you can see the second select (and others) is empty so I receive this error:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936:
>   missing expression

I don't get this error if don't use SELECT NEW, but I need it because tables (and EntityBeans) that I use in the query have only some equal fields.

Can any one tell me where it went wrong or if is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I found solution:

```
SELECT new com.*.*.MyObject(s.field1, s.field2, s.field3) 
FROM MyEntityBean1 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT 
s.field1, s.field2, s.field3 
FROM MyEntityBean2 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT ...
```

Only first SELECT must have the NEW operator.

Now I have another question, how I can use the

> ORDER BY

on this query?

I tried this:

```
SELECT s FROM (
SELECT new com.*.*.MyObject(s.field1, s.field2, s.field3) 
FROM MyEntityBean1 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT 
s.field1, s.field2, s.field3 
FROM MyEntityBean2 s WHERE s.someField = :someField UNION SELECT ...
) s ORDER BY s.someField
```

but I receive this error:

> The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression. An
>   identification variable must be provided for a range variable
>   declaration.

Any suggestion?